# How to automate SMS receiving testing with Appium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile

i'm working on test automation for a webApp and there are scenarios where i need to make sure SMS are being received correctlly by users, Current testing is built with webdriverIO so my question is how to use Appium to listen to SMS and make sure that the SMS is received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get APKINFO app and from the activity open the SMS app on activity call, after that simply select the newly received message.

Comment: thanks ,but can ou give steps in details ? i'l really new into appium